# Align sequence with curly bracket and half row shift

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, braces

Can anybody tell me how to rewrite these equations:

[image]

There are curly brackets and half row shift and I don't know how to write it in align (`eqnarray`) environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, I guess, close enough:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\newcommand{\vplus}{\begin{array}{l}\vphantom{+2=t_{1,1}}\\\vphantom{+2=t_{1,1}}\end{array}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{array}{rl}
    a_{ 1,2} & {}=  1 \\
    a_{ 2,2} & {}=  5 \\
    a_{ 3,2} & {}=  7 \\
    a_{ 4,2} & {}= 11 \\
    a_{ 5,2} & {}= 13 \\
    a_{ 6,2} & {}= 17 \\
    a_{ 7,2} & {}= 19 \\
    a_{ 8,2} & {}= 23 \\
    a_{ 9,2} & {}= 25 \\
    a_{10,2} & {}= 29 \\
    {}
  \end{array} \quad \begin{array}{r>{\hphantom{\biggr\}}}l}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\begin{array}{r}
      +4 \\ +2
    \end{array}\biggr\}\begin{array}{l}
      {}= t_{1,2} \\ {}= t_{2,2}
    \end{array}\smash{\biggr\}}} \\
    +4 & {}= t_{1,2} \\
    +2 & {}= t_{2,2} \\
    +4 & {}= t_{1,2} \\
    +2 & {}= t_{2,2} \\
    +4 & {}= t_{1,2} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\begin{array}{r}
      +2 \\ +4
    \end{array}\smash{\biggr\}}\begin{array}{l}
      {}= t_{2,2} \\ {}= t_{1,2}
    \end{array}\biggr\}} \\
    +2 & {}= t_{2,2}
  \end{array} \quad \begin{array}{l}
    \vplus\begin{array}{rl}
      6 & {}= t_{1,3}
    \end{array} \\
    \begin{array}{>{\phantom{6}}rl}
      & {}= t_{2,3} \\
      & {}= t_{3,3} \\
      & {}= t_{4,3} \\
      & {}= t_{5,3} \\
      & {}= t_{6,3}
    \end{array} \\
    \vplus\begin{array}{rl}
      6 & {}= t_{7,3} = t_{1,2} + t_{2,2}
    \end{array} \\
    \begin{array}{>{\phantom{6}}rl}
      & {}= t_{8,3}
    \end{array}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

This solution is heavily influenced by the fact that an `array` is centred vertically around the math axis.